# How can I tell a debian package to forget about a file (such that the file doesn't get deleted during a purge or remove)?

Tags: dpkg

A debian package I made overwrote files belonging to other packages (using --force-overwrite option). I realized this was bad, but after deleting these files from the package, building and reinstalling, it'll *delete* those files since it think's my package owns those files and no longer needs them.

**I need dpkg to forget my package ever knew about those files, such that I can remove/purge/install and without it ever thinking about those files again.**

Note that this package is only meant to be deployed on systems I control, not distributed to clients, so tinkering with already installed packages is acceptable, so long as I can get this back to a non-messed up state.

Couldn't find an answer on stackoverflow or [here](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html), appreciate any help or links to similar questions I missed.

Comment: I appreciate the way of asking the question it's on the point and with more clarity.

Comment: I think this question would be better on Server Fault or Super User.  You can possibly get it migrated according to this post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found that dpkg stores a list of each installed package's files here:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mydpkg.list
```

Appears to be a list of every directory and file installed by the package, eg

```
/etc/udev
/etc/udev/rules.d
/etc/udev/rules.d/95-serial485-pi3.rules
/etc/udev/rules.d/97-serial485-pi4.rules
```

**Fix:** `sudo vim /var/lib/dpkg/info/mydpkg.list` and delete lines of files I want my package to forget about, therefore not trying to delete when uninstalling (or when installing a new version of the package that doesn't have those files anymore.) Unclear on if it's necessary to delete the lines referencing parent directories (eg /etc/udev and /etc/udev/rules.d above).

**Bonus:** I found this by using strace on the command that lists these files, finding out where it gets its info from:

```
strace dpkg-query -L mydpkg
```

Taken from here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200171/where-does-dpkg-l-gather-its-information

Answer (score 1):

We can use some commands that help us to keep the package dependency and remove the package.

1. **Remove the package without removing the dependency.**

   sudo dpkg -r --force-depends <package_name>
2. **Remove the package including the configuration file and without removing the dependency.**

   sudo dpkg -P --force-depends <package_name>

I highly don't recommend this thing because sometimes **dependency may create an issue in the future.**

I always prefer to **uninstall all the dependency** when I uninstall the package.

If your package is broken then you can use the following command to resolve an issue.

**To fix the broken packages**

```
sudo apt install -f
```

I have answered this question based on this [article](https://techpiezo.com/linux/remove-a-package-without-removing-its-dependencies-in-ubuntu/).